# IEnumerable Model ElementAt method not found-

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In a razor cshtml page I invoke controller method as follows :

```
<input type="button" value=@Recognition.Views.Students.Localization.Requests.ApproveNoAutoButton 
         class="tooltip student-requests" data-tooltip="@Recognition.Views.Students.Localization.Requests.ApproveNoAutoButton" 
         style="margin-bottom: 10px;" 
         onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ApproveExamNoAuto", "Chat",
            new { EsameEstStudenteId = Model.ElementAt(0).EsameEstStudente.Id,
                  RichiestaAutorizzId = Model.ElementAt(0).RequestId });'" />
```

The controller method is declared as follows :

```
public PartialViewResult ApproveExamNoAuto(int? EsameEstStudenteId, int? RichiestaAutorizzId)
{          
    return PartialView();
}
```

The problem I have is that the parameters are always valued at null.From a more in-depth debug, it seems that it does not find the ElementAt method.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you sure `Model.ElementAt(0).EsameEstStudente.Id` is not null? It could be either `ElementAt(0)` or `EsameEstStudente`? Same for another one as well.

Comment: From a more in-depth debug, it seems that it does not find the ElementAt method

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are passing `IEnumerable` type Model to your view from your controller?

Example

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<yourmodelhere> models = ;//Getting data from somewhere
    return View(models);
}
```

Also make sure that you are using IEnumerable Model

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<yourmodelhere>
```

Comment: yes I'm passing a IEnumerable type Model to my view